# Doctrine 2.2 Autogenerated Proxy Files cannot be Autoloaded

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I have integrated Doctrine 2 with ZF1, using both the Bisna integration and my own custom integration.

The models work fine in unit tests via the shepp.

However when I run the web application, I get an error with the Proxies. The proxy for a model User.php is

```
__GC_User.php
```

and is placed in the correct location. However I get an error when the auto loader tries to load the Proxy class since its looking for

```
\_GC__\User.php
```

.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I thought that I would post an answer to help others dealing with Doctrine 2 proxies. My problem was that I was storing an entity into a Zend_Cache instance, and the entity had some Doctrine2 proxies attached.

So when I removed the caching then the issue went away. So the rule of thumb is do not store entities in Cache, just store identifiers

Comment: Could you please explain how exactly you did that, because I ran into the same problem (though not with zend)
The proxy class is namespaced like this:

\the\namespace\set\by\setProxyNamespace\__CG__\the\entity\namespace

I was expecting it to use just the namespace I set, which is the namespace before __CG__. Oh, and the generated file is \_\_CG\_\_entityclasswithnamespaceinlowercase.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You never use the Proxy class directly its used by Doctrine2 so you do not have to worry about it. Just avoid any serialization/de-serialization, storing entities in caches or object storage since the proxies cannot be handled